# State doesnt give right values after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the state and use that state of object with values to draw images on canvas. I succeeded in doing this in raw HTML but now I need react js and I am stuck at this problem. When I click on move image I want to reset the canvas, change the object from the state that was selected by id and then go through that array and draw an image for each object. It doesnt seem to be working as expected so I think I am missing something here. I tried different solutions but I didnt find anything that would help me. You can see from line 135 how the array should like before drawing images, from line 108 before drawing images I think I should have similar array.
[This is my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-haze-pqwfed?file=/src/Scene/M.js)

```
  const changeImages = useCallback((id) => {
    setImages(
      allImages.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            x: (item.x += 10)
          };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
  });
  moveButton.current.addEventListener("click", () => {
        ctx.reset();
        tex.update();
    
        let img;
        img = new Image();
        img.src =
          "https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/Front-labels/t4.png";
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        if (img) {
          changeImages(1);
    
          console.log(allImages); 
    
          allImages.forEach((e) => {
            ctx.drawImage(img, e.x, e.y, e.size, e.size);
          });
    
          tex.update();
        }
      });
```